# How are Docker Desktop proxy settings on Windows propagated to Docker?

Tags: windows, docker, proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop

I am on a corporate Windows laptop and I want to start experimenting with Docker. Being a corporate machine, everything needs to go through the corporate proxy.

I installed Debian on WSL and then the Docker Desktop, which installed its components on the Debian WSL VM. My first priority however was to test docker on WSL directly and not through Docker Desktop. So I set to read the Docker docs and download the `docker/getting-started` image through the Debian terminal. That, however, failed due to not using the network proxy.

Desktop Docker docs state that setting the proxy settings on Docker Desktop will propagate the proxy settings to Docker itself. Indeed, I set the proxy settings on Docker Desktop, and I was now able to properly download my image from inside Debian.

Since I want to have full control of Docker through the Debian terminal and not Docker Desktop, I want to understand in which way the proxy settings propagate to Docker inside WSL. I imagined that Docker Desktop altered some configuration file inside Debian, but a grep on the whole system of the proxy ip got me nothing. So my question is, in what way does the Docker Desktop let Docker know which proxy to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As much as I know, And am not 100% sure as I have not worked with docker in a while.

When you start `docker service` in WSL, this will trigger the `init.d/docker` script, And when you set the Company proxy manually in docker desktop, The loading time is :

1. Stopping Docker service
2. Updating configuration Script at `/etc/init.d/docker`
3. Starting the service again, and with it the new script

And to make sure that this is valid, You can try to check the `/etc/init.d/docker` script contents.

and as an alternative way of not adding the scripts manually. you can export the proxy configuration in WSL, and check if it will work without adding the proxy configuration to Docker Desktop.